# How to access appsettings.json from module Configure Services

Tags: module, blazor, azure-blob-storage, connection-string, appsettings

I have a blazor server side solution that contains an appsettings.json

I am configuring the blob storage in the ConfigureServices override in the Application Module of the Applications project.  It currently has a hard coded connection string and is working perfectly.

Now I want to move the connection string to the appsettings.json file that is in the Blazor project.

I've tried to inject the IConfiguration into the constructor of the ApplicationModule, but the app throws an error when I try to do so.

I've searched through the ServiceConfigurationContext passed into to the ConfigureServices override.  There is a Service property containing a collection of around 1,024 ServiceDescriptors and found one that contains the word IConfiguration in the ServiceType.FullName but haven't been able to figure out how to use it to get at the service itself in order to get at the appsettings.json values.

Can anyone shed any light on how to access the appsettings.json values from the application module?

Here is my code I am working with

```
namespace MyApp
{
    [DependsOn(
        typeof(MyAppDomainModule),
        typeof(AbpAccountApplicationModule),
        typeof(MyAppApplicationContractsModule),
        typeof(AbpIdentityApplicationModule),
        typeof(AbpPermissionManagementApplicationModule),
        typeof(AbpTenantManagementApplicationModule),
        typeof(AbpFeatureManagementApplicationModule),
        typeof(AbpSettingManagementApplicationModule),
        typeof(AbpBlobStoringModule),
        typeof(AbpBlobStoringAzureModule)
        )]
    public class MyAppApplicationModule : AbpModule
    {
        public override void ConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
        {
            Configure<AbpBlobStoringOptions>(options =>
            {
              options.Containers.ConfigureDefault(container =>
              {
                container.UseAzure(azure =>
                {
                  azure.ConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=MyApplocalsa;AccountKey=<truncated-account-key>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
                  azure.ContainerName = "Pictures";
                  azure.CreateContainerIfNotExists = true;
                });
              });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the answer to the question by looking at other modules in the solution.

Here is the updated code

```
namespace MyApp
{
    [DependsOn(
        typeof(MyAppDomainModule),
        typeof(AbpAccountApplicationModule),
        typeof(MyAppApplicationContractsModule),
        typeof(AbpIdentityApplicationModule),
        typeof(AbpPermissionManagementApplicationModule),
        typeof(AbpTenantManagementApplicationModule),
        typeof(AbpFeatureManagementApplicationModule),
        typeof(AbpSettingManagementApplicationModule),
        typeof(AbpBlobStoringModule),
        typeof(AbpBlobStoringAzureModule)
        )]
    public class MyAppApplicationModule : AbpModule
    {
        public override void ConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
        {
            var configuration = context.Services.GetConfiguration();

            Configure<AbpAutoMapperOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.AddMaps<MyAppApplicationModule>();
            });

            Configure<AbpBlobStoringOptions>(options =>
            {
              options.Containers.ConfigureDefault(container =>
              {
                container.UseAzure(azure =>
                {
                  azure.ConnectionString = configuration.GetSection("BlobStorage:ConnectionString").Value;
                  azure.ContainerName    = configuration.GetSection("BlobStorage:ContainerName").Value;
                  azure.CreateContainerIfNotExists = true;
                });
              });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I needed to add the using

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
```

I was able to get a reference to the configuration

```
var configuration = context.Services.GetConfiguration();
```

I updated the hard coded connection string with retrieving it from the configuration.

```
azure.ConnectionString = configuration.GetSection("BlobStorage:ConnectionString").Value;
azure.ContainerName    = configuration.GetSection("BlobStorage:ContainerName").Value;
```

I updated the appsettings.json file in my Blazor app

```
"BlobStorage": {
    "ConnectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=myapplocalsa;AccountKey=<truncated>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "ContainerName" :  "Pictures"
}
```

That was it!

Thank you Joe for investing your time in providing answers to my question!

Answer (score 2):

> This answer has been update based on new information in the question.

If I understand the context correctly you are building your own DI services container within `MyAppApplicationModule`.  As I don't have enough detail on `MyAppApplicationModule`, I'll demonstrate how you get to apllication configuration data in the context of `OwningComponentBase` which also defines it's own DI services container.  Note I'm using Net6.0 here.

First the configuation data in *appsettings.json* of the web project.

```json
{
  "AzureData": {
    "ConnectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=MyApplocalsa;AccountKey=<truncated-account-key>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "ContainerName":  "Pictures"
  },

  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Next define a data class to hold the configuration data

```cs
public class AzureData
{
    public readonly Guid Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string ContainerName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

Now register a configuration instance binding an `AzureData` instance  against a section in the configuration file.

```cs
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
builder.Services.Configure<AzureData>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureData"));
```

Finally the component.

Note:

1. We use `IOptions<AzureData>` to get the specific configuration instance, and `Value` to get the actual object.
2. `AzureData` is the same DI object, inside or outside the local service container.  It's defined as a singleton.

```cs
@page "/di"
@inherits OwningComponentBase
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Options

<h3>DI Component</h3>
<div class="m-2 p-2">
    Main Service Container <br />
    Id: @AzureDataConfig?.Value.Id <br />
    Connection String: @AzureDataConfig?.Value.ConnectionString
</div>
<div class="m-2 p-2">
    Component Service Container <br />
    Id:@azureData?.Value.Id <br />
    Connection String: @azureData?.Value.ConnectionString
</div>

@code {

    [Inject] private IOptions<AzureData>? AzureDataConfig { get; set; }

    private IOptions<AzureData>? azureData;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        azureData = ScopedServices.GetService<IOptions<AzureData>>();   
        base.OnInitialized();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've updated my post above to include the module I am trying to access the appsettings.json from.  Dependency Injection fails to pass in IConfiguration into a constructor and I don't know how to get the IConfiguration from the ServiceConfigurationContext passed into ConfigureServices override.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Joe - I've updated my answer.  Am I guessing right about the context of `MyAppApplicationModule`?

Comment: I apologize for not being clear enough.  My goal is to pass a connection string from an appsettings.json into the module above so I don't need to hardcode the connection string in the line "azure.ConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=MyApplocalsa;AccountKey=<truncated-account-key>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";".    I am struggling to understand how to any value from appsettings.json into the module.   Injecting IConfiguration into the constructor is failing and I can't figure out how to get at it from the ServiceConfigurationContext passed into ConfigureServices.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to update your answer above! @MrC aka Shaun Curtis

Answer (score 0):

For others who might be looking for a solution to the same problem - I have a couple of things to add. I was using a separated tenant with separate `Product.IdentityServer`, `Product.Web`, and `Product.HttpApi.Host` projects.

The configuration I was trying to perform was for the `AbpTwilioSmsModule` and `AbpBlobStoringModule`. The values for these modules were hardcoded into my
`Product.Domain.ProductDomainModule` class.

```cs
    // TODO - Need to configure this through appsettings.json - JLavallet 2022-02-10 12:23  
    Configure<AbpTwilioSmsOptions>(options =>
    {
      options.AccountSId = "yada-yada-yada";
      options.AuthToken = "yada-yada-yada";
      options.FromNumber = "+18885551212";
    });
    // TODO - Need to configure this through appsettings.json  - JLavallet 2022-02-10 12:24 
    Configure<AbpBlobStoringOptions>(options =>
    {
      options.Containers.ConfigureDefault(container =>
      {
        container.IsMultiTenant = true;
        container.UseFileSystem(fileSystem => { fileSystem.BasePath = @"D:\Product\DevFiles"; });
      });
    });
```

I modified that code to try and read from the context just like the OP. I wasn't sure what property of the context contained the configuration. I tried all kind of things and set breakpoints to try and find the configuration object in the context without success.

```cs
        Configure<AbpTwilioSmsOptions>(options =>
        {
          options.AccountSId = context.WHAT?["AbpTwilioSms:AccountSId"]; 
          options.AuthToken = context.WHAT?["AbpTwilioSms:AuthToken"]; 
          options.FromNumber = context.WHAT?["AbpTwilioSms:FromNumber"]; 
        });

        Configure<AbpBlobStoringOptions>(options =>
        {
          options.Containers.ConfigureDefault(container =>
          {
            container.IsMultiTenant = Convert.ToBoolean(context.WHAT?["AbpBlobStoring:IsMultiTenant"]);
            container.UseFileSystem(fileSystem =>
            {
              fileSystem.BasePath = context.WHAT?["AbpBlobStoring:FileSystemBasePath"];
            });
          });
        });
```

At that point I came across this post and found how to get the configuration object out of the context.

Not all was well, however…

For the longest time I could not understand why I could not read my `appsettings.json` configuration information that I had placed in the `Product.HttpApi.Host` root folder. I was able to get to the configuration object but my values were still `null`.

I then had the thought that I should add an `appsettings.json` file to my `Product.Domain` root folder; surprisingly that had no effect.

I finally came around to moving the service configuration code out of my `Product.Domain.ProductDomainModule` class and into my `Product.HttpApi.Host.ProductHttpApiHostModule` class and my `Product.IdentityServer.ProductIdentityServerModule` class.

```cs
    [DependsOn(
      typeof(ProductHttpApiModule),
      typeof(AbpAutofacModule),
      typeof(AbpCachingStackExchangeRedisModule),
      typeof(AbpAspNetCoreMvcUiMultiTenancyModule),
      typeof(AbpIdentityAspNetCoreModule),
      typeof(ProductApplicationModule),
      typeof(ProductEntityFrameworkCoreModule),
      typeof(AbpSwashbuckleModule),
      typeof(AbpAspNetCoreSerilogModule)
    )]
    // added by Jack 
    [DependsOn(typeof(AbpTwilioSmsModule))]
    [DependsOn(typeof(AbpBlobStoringModule))]
    [DependsOn(typeof(AbpBlobStoringFileSystemModule))]
    public class ProductHttpApiHostModule : AbpModule
    {
      public override void ConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
      {
        var configuration = context.Services.GetConfiguration();
        var hostingEnvironment = context.Services.GetHostingEnvironment();

        ConfigureUrls(configuration);
        ConfigureConventionalControllers();
        ConfigureAuthentication(context, configuration);
        ConfigureSwagger(context, configuration);
        ConfigureCache(configuration);
        ConfigureVirtualFileSystem(context);
        ConfigureDataProtection(context, configuration, hostingEnvironment);
        ConfigureCors(context, configuration);
        ConfigureExternalProviders(context);
        ConfigureHealthChecks(context);
        ConfigureTenantResolver(context, configuration);
    
        //added by Jack 
        ConfigureTwilioSms(configuration);
        ConfigureBlobStoring(configuration);
      }
    
      private void ConfigureBlobStoring(IConfiguration configuration)
      {
        Configure<AbpBlobStoringOptions>(options =>
        {
          options.Containers.ConfigureDefault(container =>
          {
            container.IsMultiTenant = Convert.ToBoolean(configuration["AbpBlobStoring:IsMultiTenant"]);
            container.UseFileSystem(fileSystem =>
            {
              fileSystem.BasePath = configuration["AbpBlobStoring:FileSystemBasePath"];
            });
          });
        });
      }
    
      private void ConfigureTwilioSms(IConfiguration configuration)
      {
        Configure<AbpTwilioSmsOptions>(options =>
        {
          options.AccountSId = configuration["AbpTwilioSms:AccountSId"]; 
          options.AuthToken = configuration["AbpTwilioSms:AuthToken"]; 
          options.FromNumber = configuration["AbpTwilioSms:FromNumber"]; 
        });
      }
```

I then copied my configuration entries from the `Product.HttpApi.Host\appsettings.json` file into my `Product.IdentityServer\appsettings.json` file and everything worked beautifully.

```json
    {
      ...,
      "AbpTwilioSms": {
        "AccountSId": "yada-yada-yada",
        "AuthToken": "yada-yada-yada",
        "FromNumber": "+18885551212"
      },
      "AbpBlobStoring": {
        "IsMultiTenant": true,
        "FileSystemBasePath": "D:\\Product\\DevFiles\\"
      }
    }
```